# whats wrong with this function? where did i make mistake?

Tags: c++

I have this function declaration and its defination:

### declaration

```
void laodFromFile(
      string const& fileName,
      Frames& frames,
      ostream&  log =std::clog);
```

defination:

```
void loadFromFile(
        string const&   fileName,
        Frames&         frames,
        ostream&        log =std::clog
        )
    {
        using std::endl;
        using std::ifstream;

        string const    streamDescription   = "text data file " + fileName;

        log << "Opening " << streamDescription << " for reading..." << endl;

        ifstream    stream( fileName.c_str() );
        (!stream.fail())
            || throwX( S() << "Error opening " << streamDescription << "." );

        loadFrom( stream, frames, streamDescription, log );
    }
```

**error:**

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl soundData::laodFromFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class soundData::Frames &,class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?laodFromFile@soundData@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAVFrames@1@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@3@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl cppMain(int,char const * const * const)" (?cppMain@@YAXHQBQBD@Z) C:\lacture\loading frames\loading frames\main.obj   loading frames
```

what is wrong with that function? any one can guide me...
Expecting a good response thanks

Comment: Is the typo "load" vs "laod" in your actual code?

Comment: You're working too hard. `return std::istringstream(std::ifstream(fileName).rdbuf()).str();` ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a spelling mistake LoadFromFile and LaodFromFile...

Comment: haha. Obvious mistakes are never obvious until someone else is watching :)

Comment: error: Error 1 error C2572: 'soundData::loadFromFile' : redefinition of default parameter : parameter 3 c:\loading frames\loading frames\sounddata.cpp 111 1 loading frames

Comment: @Miss just put the `=std::clog` in the declaration of the function; not the definition. You don't need it (and indeed, can't have it) in both declaration and definition.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 5):

You've got `laodFromFile` somewhere, and `loadFromFile` somewhere else. Fix your typos.